# Cannot lock mutex in C

Tags: c, mutex, waitforsingleobject

I want to create a lock for writing to a log file.
I need to use a mutex, though it seems that my implementation is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

void main() {
    HANDLE lock=CreateMutex (
            NULL,           // default security attributes
            FALSE,          // initial owner
            NULL);          // unnamed mutex
    if (lockMutex == NULL) 
        printf("CreatelockMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    WaitForSingleObject(lock, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(lock, INFINITE);
    printf("I've PASSED the lock!!");
}
```

the first 'WaitForSingleObject' should pass, (no one acquired the lock) but the second 'WaitForSingleObject' should stuck the program, but it does't happen..
what am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK mutexes on Windows are recursive, i.e. the thread the has locked it is allowed to lock it again, as long as it released the lock the same number of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateMutex` creates a 'recursive' mutex, i.e. the mutex can be acquired repeatedly by the same thread. Another thread would not be able to acquire it. And that makes perfect sense.

If you need to create a non-recursive mutex, use `CreateSemaphore` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft's docs:
"The thread that owns a mutex can specify the same mutex in repeated wait function calls without blocking its execution."

Try with two threads...